# Invalid cast Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.HierarchyId

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, graphql

I use GraphQl to fetch the data, here is my method in order to get the result based on category ID.

```
    public IQueryable<Product> GetActiveProducts( string categoryId, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    =>_dDbContext.Categories.Where(x => x.Id == categoryId);  
     ...
```

Also, my entity is as follows:

```
 public class Category:IEntityHierarchy
  {

    public string Id { get; set; }
    // code removed for brevity
```

and also IEntityHierarchy

```
  public class IEntityHierarchy
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
  }
```

The configuration of my category entity is:

```
 builder.Property( x => x.Id )
             .HasConversion(
                            v =>HierarchyId.Parse( v ),
                            v => v.ToString() ) ;
```

When I call the endpoint, it throws an error: **Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.HierarchyId**

And here is also my query:

```
query($categoryId:String!){
  activeProducts(categoryId:$categoryId)
  {
    id
    name
  }
}
// and query valiables
{
  "categoryId":"/2/7/"
}
```

I also should mention that when I directly provide the category ID in my Linq query, it works.

```
    public IQueryable<Product> GetActiveProducts( string categoryId, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    =>_dDbContext.Categories.Where(x =>x.Id == "/2/7/"); 
     ...
```

**Update 1:**
I have two models for write and read, in write model the Category entity uses HirerachyId, and in read model I want to use string instead.

Comment: `hierarchyid` isn't a string, it's a binary value. CQRS has nothing to do with the question and definitely doesn't justify using the wrong database type. If you want your *GraphQL* model to use a different type, then the *GraphQL* entity type should have a different property, and the resolver should map between database and DTO type

Comment: `the CQRS pattern and separated read and write,` that's not what CQRS says either. The acronym says Command-Query Responsibility Separation, not rear/write separation. It talks about the high-level model exposed to the world (in this case your GraphQL Schema), not how you talk to the database. GraphQL already separates Queries and Mutations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but my issue still persists, that's why I used the HasConversion, and of course if I use e,g, "/2/7/" directly in my Linq query I get no error, but when I change it to my parameter (categoryId) then I will get the error.

Comment: `HasConversion` **is** the issue. Remove it. Parse the string into a HierarchyID *before* you try to use your database entities. The error is caused because you're trying to directly map the string in your GraphQL type to a different type in your EF Core entity. These aren't the same.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a different type in GraphQL, like [ID](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/scalars#id). Or create a custom scalar type. This isn't an EF problem, it's a GraphQL and HotChocolate mapping issue. In fact, if you want clients to be able to send valid hierarchy values to the server, you *do* need to specify a custom scalar with its own validation

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using a string as the Id in the Entity then there's no need for that HasConversion configuration.  You can just read and write the string Id to the database.

If you do want to use the Conversion so you're using strongly typed ids in the entity then the Id should be defined as type HierarchyId:

```
  public class IEntityHierarchy
  {
    public HierarchyId Id { get; set; }
  }
```

and also in your implementation:

```
 public class Category:IEntityHierarchy
  {

    public HierarchyId Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: I follow the CQRS pattern and separated read and write, in my write model the Category entity uses HirerachyId, but in read model I want to use string instead.

Comment: @Ocelot CQRS has nothing to do with the question. Using the wrong type is a major bug, as bad as using a string for dates or decimals. `HierarchyID` isn't a string, it's a binary value. `/123/23527/45` is a formatted value, not the actual value